# How to return a URL without a subfolder/subdirectory (using PHP not htaccess)

Tags: php, subdirectory

The question basically covers it. I'm sure this question has been asked, but I can't seem to find it.

Just to be clear, I have this url

https://www.example.com/subfolder/page.php

and I'd like to return with this url

https://www.example.com/page.php

I think I'm supposed to use http_build_url() but alas, I am here.

I know that this can be done with .htaccess, but for my specifically weird situation, I need it to be done in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simply, you could just redirect with:

```php
header('location: example.com/page.php');
```

With `http_build_url()` as you wanted, you could do:

```
echo http_build_url("http://example.com/subfolder/page.php",
array(
    "scheme" => "http",
    "host" => "example.com",
    "path" => "/page.php"
),
HTTP_URL_STRIP_AUTH | HTTP_URL_JOIN_PATH | HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY | HTTP_URL_STRIP_FRAGMENT
);
```